# PDO Bind Offset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get this SQL to run, however when I use PDO it just displays nothing, I think its something to do with the ":offset" because if I remove that and type a number, it works fine. the offset variable is correct and functions as its supposed to

```
$newsQuery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY News_ID DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET :offset");
      echo $offset;
      $newsQuery->bindParam(":offset", $offset,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $newsQuery->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newsQuery->bindParam(":offset", intval($offset), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

For some reason, `PDO::PARAM_INT` is not enough. It is still passed as string. So, forcing an integer conversion bypasses this inconvenience.

*Note: I've recently faced this myself.*

Comment: this gives me an error "Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2"

Comment: try `LIMIT 6, :offset` instead of `Limit 6 OFFSET :offset ` . That should work

Comment: Nope, my ide is flagging an error on "(int) $offset" saying only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: hmmm... `intval($offset)`?

Comment: Thank you! I added that, then put the OFFSET back into the statement and its working now :D

Comment: You have to understand the difference betweem bindparam and bindvalue

Comment: @YourCommonSense, lesson learnt! (gonna pay a bit more attention to that. I usually use `bindValue` and with that i can also pass values)

Answer (score -1):

Just replace below line

```
$newsQuery->bindParam(":offset", $offset,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

With

```
$newsQuery->bindParam("offset", $offset,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Where ever you have to bind :parameter do not use : sign while bind time.